# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'FilterMetadata' on primeng table

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, angular11, primeng-datatable

I am migrating a module from primeng 7 to primeng11 along with angular11 the code runs perfectly fine on ng serve the functionalities are working too but on build I am getting a weird error

```
 error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'FilterMetadata | FilterMetadata[]'.
  Property 'value' does not exist on type 'FilterMetadata'.
```

the error is for the below code

```
<input *ngIf='!col.noFilter' [style.width]="'98%'" [style.height]="'25px'" pInputText type="text"
                        [placeholder]="col.filterPlaceHolder ? col.filterPlaceHolder : ''" 
                        (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)" 
                        [value]="dt.filters[col.field]?.value" />
```

I have verified the primeng `FilterMetaData` interface and it has the property value like below

```
export interface FilterMetadata {
    value?: any;
    matchMode?: string;
    operator?: string;
}
```

the code syntax is fine i have veriified the same on primeng page docuemntation https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table

Please kindly help not sure why ng serve has no ssues but build is failing. My node version is node v10.23.0

Answer (score 12):

***Angular/PrimeNg: 12+***

This works for me:

**Note:** You can see the `$any` usage here.

```
 <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($any($event.target)?.value, 'name', 'contains')"
 [value]="$any(dt.filters['name'])?.value" placeholder="Search by Name" class="p-column-filter">
```

**Ref:** https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35293#issuecomment-584293328

Answer (score 0):

try replacing this line

```
[value]="dt.filters[col.field]?.value
```

with this other

```
[value]="$any(dt).filters[col.field]?.value"
```

I hope it works for you

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo in your syntax. I hope you are using the global search functionality and the syntax should be **(input)="dt.filterGlobal()"** instead of  **(input)="dt.filter()"**.

```
<input *ngIf='!col.noFilter' [style.width]="'98%'" [style.height]="'25px'" pInputText type="text" [placeholder]="col.filterPlaceHolder ? col.filterPlaceHolder : ''" (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode) />
```

Comment: No these are individual filters at column level.. not global filter.

Comment: Did you set the match mode in the column definitions?

{field: 'name', headerName: 'Name', filterMatchMode: 'contains'}